# Remove 3.x version and keep the latest compiled

Tags: python, python-3.x

currently I have 3 Python versions on my computer:

2.7 - I don't want to remove this version because of the many dependencies with Debian 10

Python 3.7.3 - I want to remove this version because I have the latest one

Python 3.8.1 - I want to keep this version and get rid of 3.7

Is this possible and how?

Regards,

Comment: What OS are you using? Are there uninstallers for these other versions?

Comment: You might want to make sure Python 3.7 isn't a dependency either. I know Ubuntu 18.04 (based on Debian) for example requires Python 3.6.

Comment: @SyntaxRules, I'm using Debian 10.





wjandrea, If I run "apt remove python3" the uninstall and not needed anymore list is HUGE and Gnome, and many other services will be removed. I will not remove Python3 this way because I will lose the whole system.

Comment: Leave any thing that was installed by your system as-is, and use virtual environments to manage the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, Python 3.7 is a dependency of Gnome and other important Debian programs, so you can't remove it.

Based on [my experience with Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/1061249/301745) (which is based on Debian), you shouldn't even change the default system-wide Python 3 version at `/usr/bin/python3` since some system programs rely on that path.

But what you could do at least is [set up an alias](https://askubuntu.com/questions/320996/how-to-make-python-program-command-execute-python-3) to make it the default Python 3 version for your user. Put this in your ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_aliases:

```
alias python3=python3.8
```

Then in Bash you can use `python3` to run `python3.8`. Shebangs are not affected by aliases though; you'll need to keep using the same shebangs.

Comment: you are right I was thinking about the same solution. :)
Thank you